# npm ERR! user is not allowed to access package @gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources : @gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am working with nodejs and 'Jenkins' every day now for the past few months.
Without making any changes to my package.json. Building my project at 'jenkins' I get the following error -

```
gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/musichords/public/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '@gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/musichords/public/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/index.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)


npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@4.3.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@4.3.2
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_0.12.9/bin/node" "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_0.12.9/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.9
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.9
npm ERR! code E403

npm ERR! user developers is not allowed to access package @gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources : @gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources
npm ERR!
```

I've ran npm update, removed and reinstalled npm, installed 'gulp-sourcemaps' and a few more dependencies. Nothing seems to work.

my dependencies at 'package.json'-

```
"dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^5.0.0",
    "async": "^1.5.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.2.26",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.1.0",
    "bytes": "^2.2.0",
    "cheerio": "^0.20.0",
    "collections": "^3.0.0",
    "convert-source-map": "^1.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "csv": "^0.4.6",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "extend": "^3.0.0",
    "detect-newline": "^2.1.0",
    "debug-fabulous": "^0.0.4",
    "geoip-lite-youtab": "*",
    "glob": "^7.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sourcemap": "^1.0.1",
    "imagemin": "^5.2.0",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^5.0.0",
    "imagemin-jpegtran":"^5.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng":"^5.0.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "jstransformer-clean-css": "^1.1.0",
    "jstransformer-uglify-js": "^1.1.1",
    "jstransformer-verbatim": "1.0.0",
    "lru-cache": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.11.0",
    "needle": "^1.0.0",
    "neo4j": "2.0.0-RC2",
    "newrelic": "^1.24.1",
    "node-genres": "*",
    "optipng-bin": "^3.1.2",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.7.1",
    "source-map": "^0.5.6",
    "string": "^3.3.1",
    "text-encoding": "^0.6.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "underscore.string": "^3.2.2",
    "winston": "^2.1.1",
    "ytf-node-framework": "*",
    "ytf-server": "*",
    "ytf-server-commons": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.4.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-shell": "^1.1.2",
    "mocha": "^2.3.4",
    "spec-xunit-file": "^0.0.1-3",
    "superagent-no-cache": "^0.1.0",
    "supertest": "^1.1.0",
    "tizi": "*"
  }
```

Appreciate any assistance I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by explicitly setting the registry for that scope to be the npmjs registry.

`npm config set @gulp-sourcemaps:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

I believe updating your .npmrc file to include it would also work:

`@gulp-sourcemaps:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org`

Comment: This worked for me, the other answer didn't, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We also encountered this with an older npm version, but even upgrading to 4.4.4 didn't help.  Removing the ^ worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem this morning with my own build. It would appear that the authors of `gulp-sourcemaps` added a [scoped dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) to their `package.json` [two days ago](https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps/commit/b9adcf5e8a5b815c1ba280ac4c3cb4caa1da74da#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2). I'm not familiar with scoped dependencies, but it would appear that's what causing `npm install` to fail. I am on an older version of npm that doesn't have support for scoped dependencies, but it looks like you're on a newer version - it could be that they haven't published the dependency yet, or set it public since scoped dependencies default to private.

As a short-term fix, you can do as I did, and remove the `^` from your version specifier for `gulp-sourcemaps` in your own `package.json`, which will avoid pulling the latest version of `gulp-sourcemaps` that has the new scoped dependency.